# stack exec keeps running "git clone

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a script running which is going to "stack exec" my program over a large number of test files. In my logs, I intermittently start seeing things like this appearing:

```html
Running /usr/bin/git clone --recursive git@github.com:dvekeman/language-java.git "/Users/jkoppel/Dropbox (MIT)/research/compstrat/languages/.stack-work/downloaded/DD9RxfiWfxTw" in directory /Users/jkoppe\
l/Dropbox (MIT)/research/compstrat/languages/.stack-work/downloaded/ exited with ExitFailure 128


Cloning into '/Users/jkoppel/Dropbox (MIT)/research/compstrat/languages/.stack-work/downloaded/DD9RxfiWfxTw'...
fatal: unable to open /Users/jkoppel/Dropbox (MIT)/research/compstrat/languages/.stack-work/downloaded/DD9RxfiWfxTw/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_aTga2a: No such file or directory
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I do have `git@github.com:dvekeman/language-java.git` as a dependency in my `stack.yaml`, but the program is already built. Why does it keep doing this, and how do I make it stop?